# How does this V4 Navigation look like now it's V6?

Tags: react-native

I would like to convert the following react-navigation code (v4) to v6. What will the following now look like? This is in each of my screens.

```
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import { TransitionPresets } from 'react-navigation-stack';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
 ...
)}

OtpScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        header: () => null,
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
    }
}

export default withNavigation(MyScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, you can add your options directly inside the navigator definition.
After install the npm packages, for a stack navigator try this:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';
... 

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions ={... // your global options here}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
          ...TransitionPresets. SlideFromRightIOS,
          ...  // others specific options
          }}
      />;
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Then in your App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MyStack from ../path/to/file
... // others imports

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MyStack />
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

WithNavigation has been removed since v5.
Here is the link to the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator)

Comment: Would this be in App.js for example, not in the inidividual MyScreen i posted the code to itself?

Comment: Yes it could be in your App.js for a really simple App. For a bigger one you should define you navigator in a separate file (e.g Navigator.js) and then import it and render it in your App.js. But definitely not in your individual screen

Comment: @chai86 I've updated the response with an exemple in App.js

Comment: So the code above code with MyStack() would be in Navigator.js? Then you have App.js as you have defined. What if i have my screen (called MyScreen with the StyleSheet etc...in my code snippet above)? I take it TransitionPresets moves into the Navigator.js?

Comment: @chai86 Yes you define your screen options (TransitionPresets or whatever) in the navigator either in the Stack.Screen options for the specific options for a specific screen or in the Stack.Navigator screenOptions if all of your screens have the same options like in the exemple with MyStack(). Here is the doc for the screen options : reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options